# How to check if a text in a Popup TextField is in a strict range numbers

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem I want to check if a text in a Popup TextField is in a strict range numbers but when I tried to use `||`, `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` I got an error:

> this operator cannot be used with a String and an Int

:(

That I want to do :

```
//here I want to check 

if field.text is in a range of numbers like if field.text <= 10 || >=1{
 //do whatever I want that method doesn't work
}
```

The code:

```
func changelogPopup(){
    let changeLog1 = UIAlertController(title: "CHANGELOG", message: "Veuillez choisir la version pour laquelle vous souhaitez voir le changelog :", preferredStyle: .alert)
    changeLog1.addAction(UIAlertAction (title: "Continuer", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

        let field = changeLog1.textFields?[0] as! UITextField

        if field.text == "1"{ 
            self.changeLog1P()
        }

    }))
    changeLog1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Annuler et sortir", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    changeLog1.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Numéro de Build de la version"
    }

    self.present(changeLog1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thank you so much for helping.

Louis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first check if it is not empty, then convert the textfield text into a number and now you can use all the number operators for it.

You can convert with:

```
let textfieldInt: Int! = Int(field.text!)
if (textfieldInt <= 10 || textfieldInt >= 1)
...
```

Comment: @LouisLegout you can upvote or accept  the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: First you check if its not empty THEN you convert.

Comment: If you read the answer there is written, I have writed the code to resolve only the issue: number operation to string, not all the controller.

Comment: `let textfieldInt: Int! = Int(field.text!)` you wrote this, no? what will happen the field is empty? So yes, you resolved the issue but opened the door for a new one...

Comment: "..into a number (check if it is not empty)..." I was referring to this.

Comment: What you meant to say is correct, but what you have written reads something else. I have submitted an edit correcting the (english) syntax.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

The textfieldObj.text is of type String. So, you can not apply mathemetical operation on String.
So, you have to convert String to Integer / number before the comparision.

Example:

```
let field = changeLog1.textFields?[0] as! UITextField
let parsedNumber = Integer(field.text) // nil, if user typed non numeric.
    // if parsedNumber <= 10 || >=1{ 
    if (parsedNumber <= 10 || parsedNumber >= 1) {
        self.changeLog1P()
    }
```

For safety, to avoid keying non numeric text, change the text filed input keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad.

```
changeLog1.textFields[0].keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I tried that I got an error Expected '{' after if condition let fieldInt = Int(field.text!)
            if (fieldInt != nil) <=10 || >=1{
                
            }

Comment: You must insert a space:    `if parsedNumber <= 10 || >= 1 {`